# Excel VBA Error Doing Multiple Row Multiplication

Tags: excel, macros, excel-formula, vba

Gettin a "Type Mismatch" error.

Trying to take one matrix of numbers on one worksheet "Sheet1", divide by another matrix of numbers on a second worksheet "Sheet2", then show each cell result on a matrix on the third worksheet "Sheet1"

```
Sub MacroTest()

Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C5") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:DR124") / Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C5:DR124")

End Sub
```

Comment: shouldn't this be tagged Excel-VBA?

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed and now is tagged as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you can do what you need on specific range (that you can choose) on different sheet and also on the same sheet.

```
Sub RangeDiv()
    Dim RngFrom As Range
    Dim RngDiv As Range
    Dim RngTo As Range

    Dim R As Integer
    Dim C As Integer

    Set RngFrom = Sheets(1).Range("A1:E3")
    Set RngDiv = Sheets(1).Range("B6:F8")
    Set RngTo = Sheets(1).Range("C10:G12")

    'Check if all Rngs have the same number of rows and columns
    If RngFrom.Rows.Count <> RngDiv.Rows.Count Or RngFrom.Rows.Count <> RngTo.Rows.Count Then
        MsgBox ("Rngs rows number aren't equal")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If RngFrom.Columns.Count <> RngDiv.Columns.Count Or RngFrom.Columns.Count <> RngTo.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox ("Rngs columns number aren't equal")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For C = 1 To RngFrom.Columns.Count
        For R = 1 To RngFrom.Rows.Count
            'check cell value to avoid errors coming from dividing by 0
            If Val(RngDiv.Cells(R, C)) <> 0 Then
                RngTo.Cells(R, C) = RngFrom.Cells(R, C) / RngDiv.Cells(R, C)
            Else
                'Insert something when division is impossible
                RngTo.Cells(R, C) = 0 'Or what you want to insert
            End If
        Next R
    Next C
End Sub
```

Comment: I have cells with blank fields that I can't do anything with, so this gave me an overflow error. I re-wrote it to include an if/then loop to catch nulls but I ended up with a matrix full of zero's - what's the right way to write this? 

    For C = 1 To RngFrom.Columns.Count
        For R = 1 To RngFrom.Rows.Count
            If IsEmpty(RngTo.Cells(R, C)) = True Then
            RngTo.Cells(R, C) = 0
            Else
            RngTo.Cells(R, C) = RngFrom.Cells(R, C) / RngDiv.Cells(R, C)
            End If

Comment: @Danimov82 I edited my code to prevent division by 0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late reply.

You can solve your problem with a for-loop:

```
For i = 3 To 9
    If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Tabelle2").Cells(5, i).Value) And IsNumeric(Worksheets("Tabelle3").Cells(5, i).Value) And Worksheets("Tabelle3").Cells(5, i).Value <> 0 Then
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(5, i).Value = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Cells(5, i).Value / Worksheets("Tabelle3").Cells(5, i).Value
    End If
Next
```

**variable i** is your column as a number. A = 1, B = 2, Z = 26, AA = 27 and so on..
**number 5** is your row

For example
Cells(5,1) is the same like Range("A5") or Cells(3,9) = Range("I3")

In my code above, it starts with column C (3) and stops with column I (9). Replace the Number 9 with the number of the Column FX (your last column) and edit the table Names then it should work.

Comment: Getting same error with the following modification 

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5") = Worksheets("Month Gross Demand").Range("C5:FX5") / Worksheets("Month Order Count").Range("C5:FX5")

Comment: What i meant was, that its not possible to use a "Range". Its only possible to calculate with  one specific column / row. For Example C5 or A3 or B9 but not C5:FX5 or A1:B3

Comment: These matrices have hundreds of values, which would require me to write hundreds of lines of code using that method - there has to be a way to build a smaller function

Comment: So you want to display the result in Sheet1 Cell C5 of  the sum of C5:FX5 in sheet Gross Demand divide through sum of C5:FX5 in sheet Order Count? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: No, I'd want to see the value of Sheet 2 - C5 divided by Sheet 3 - C5 to be displayed in Sheet 3 - C5, and so on throughout the matrix of numbers. So Sheet 3 - D5 would be Sheet 1 - D5 divided by Sheet 2 - D5 and so on.

Comment: How do you handle division by zero as I have cells with no values and can't remove

Comment: ive edited the code again. With the isnumeric()-function you can check if the cell has a numeric value. With the condition "<> 0", the macro will only calulate, when the value in table3 is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I create sheet1 like this

[Please click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdcKA.png)

then sheet2

[Please click to see Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVV5N.png)

then create blank sheet 3

and use this code

```
Sub divideRange()
    Dim lastRow, lastColumn As Long

    lastColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        For j = 1 To lastColumn
            Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, j).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value / Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Quick follow up - If I'm starting both tables on C3 as the top left hand corner, and ending at the bottom right hand corner of the matrix as DR124 - how would this script look differently? The only reason I ask is that running this is causing an overflow error so I assume it's because the matrix is set up differently than your example.

Comment: I have a handful of cells with 0's in them, so this may be because the formula is trying to divide by zero. How would I get around cells with blanks / 0's? I can't get rid of them, as it's a populated data set from power pivot so need some kind of "if blank then ignore" function added to this but unclear what that might look like.